# paraview RequestData called once

Tags: vtk, paraview

I have created a paraview filter in C++. The problem is when I press apply button the filter works and show me the result but if I try it again (after any change in properties input), the RequestData function is not called anymore. This problem never appear when I used Python programmable filter. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're calling `this->Modified()` in the method that gets called after the property is changed e.g.

```
void SetMyValue(double value)
{
   ...
   this->Modified();
}
```

You probably want to check that the value or some other state of your filter is changed which could potentially change the output of the filter before calling `this->Modified()`. Otherwise the filter may unnecessarily update and produce the exact same result. You can look at `vtkSetGet.h` for macros that do that (look at `#define vtkSetMacro(name,type)` ).